# for loop not picking up all values from beautifulsoup scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am just playing around and trying to learn web scraping using python with requests and beautifulsoup. I am not able to loop like some instructions I tried to follow.

What I am trying to accomplish is simply output the date, and a list of the teams from this page: http://www.vegasinsider.com/mlb/odds/las-vegas/

Here is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from flask import render_template
from testApp import app
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

source = requests.get('http://www.vegasinsider.com/mlb/odds/las-vegas/').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")

tbl = soup.find('table', class_='frodds-data-tbl')

for matchups in tbl.find_all('td', class_= 'viCellBg1'):
    gameDate = matchups.span.text
    print(gameDate)

    team = matchups.b.a.text
    print(team)

    print()
```

when trying to execute, it will first fail on the setting of the "`gameDate`" variable with `"AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'",)`

I was under the impression that once I have the object I want to target, I can loop through and cascade down the markup to locate the text I am looking for, but this didn't work.

Could someone look at my above code and tell me what i'm doing wrong? I greatly appreciate any help and insight on this, since I'm pretty new.

Thanks!

Comment: Your expected output is stll unclear.

Comment: `matchups.span.text` error in `.text`. Debug the code to check it is having `'text` attribute or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if span exists inside the matchup, try this:

```
source = requests.get('http://www.vegasinsider.com/mlb/odds/las-vegas/').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")
tbl = soup.find('table', class_='frodds-data-tbl')

for matchups in tbl.find_all('td', class_= 'viCellBg1'):
    if matchups.span is not None:
        gameDate = matchups.span.text
        print(gameDate)

    for b_ in matchups.find_all('b'):
        print(b_.a.text)
```

Comment: This was the resolution, thank you. In the case of how this html was structured, I just had to modify this code a bit to find two td classes: 

for matchups in tbl.find_all('td', {'class': ['viCellBg1', 'viCellBg2']}):